# Submit Website Button using Java

Tags: java, html

I want to submit a button on a website using Java. The websites button code is as follows:

```
<button type="submit" class="button-class button-class-name">
                 BUTTON NAME
</button>
```

I have a problem though, I can't seem to send a POST request to submit the button. My goal is to "press" multiple buttons simulating a browser, but to do it very quickly. Here is my code for sending a post request.

```
PostMethod addToCart = new PostMethod(url);

NameValuePair data[] = {
new NameValuePair("button-class button-class-name", "submit"),
};

addToCart.setRequestBody(data);

InputStream in = addToCart.getResponseBodyAsStream();
//Handles Response
```

I don't know if my way is the incorrect way to go about this, but my overall goal is to press a button on one page have it bring me to the next page fill out a couple of forms and finally submit. I am pretty positive that I am doing this totally wrong and I have searched for a while, and I can't find anywhere to start.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the HttpClient tutorial - http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html.  From your code snippet you don't seem to be executing the post, so there's never going to be a response.

Comment: Love colorful class names

Comment: I have already tried the HttpClient, but I recently found http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/ and that seems very promising. If anyone has used http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/ before could they point me in the right direction?

Comment: why can't you use Jquery/Ajax to POST and submit any data if required & return a response object..this seems to be much easier than you might think..